# Datastax Opscenter 5.0.2 multiple versions detected

Tags: version, datastax, opscenter

Working with `Datastax` `OpsCenter 5.0.2`, community edition installed.  I have a 34 node cluster, with the nodes spread out across 2 DCs.  All Nodes are Normal. The DataStax agent is installed on all nodes.

At the top of the Dashboard is an error that states: `Multiple versions detected (More Info)`.

The More Info link lists all 34 nodes, with their `Cassandra` versions listed. Some nodes show the correct version, others show the previous version.

If I run `./nodetool version` on the incorrect nodes, the correct version is displayed.

I have tried to bounce the `DataStax` agent on the incorrect nodes, but the incorrect version remains.